How to create custom row aggregates in R's DT library
Goal
I would like to produce row aggregates for a table grouped by the rowGroup extension to the DT library. I am able to group the data frame with rowGroup but am unclear how to populate aggregated values in the summary rows.
What I've tried
Consulting examples in the DT documentation, here and here I believe the answer lies in using rowGroup.startRender. However, I am unclear how to implement this in the R DT library rowGroup extension.
Desired Output
I would like to get the number of samples per group as well as the average weight by group.

Code
DT::datatable(chickwts,
              rownames = TRUE,
              extensions="RowGroup",
              options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc=c(2),
                                             columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(2))))
              ))

Update
@stefan's answer works, but there is a limitation that aggregate values are only based on the records presently displayed rather than the total number of records in the group.


Is there perhaps a way to generate aggregates based on the structure of the underlying data rather than those records that are displayed at any given moment?

Adapting the example in the referenced links you can achieve your desired result by adding a custom JS render function to the startRender attribute of the rowGroup list:
DT::datatable(chickwts,
  rownames = TRUE,
  extensions = "RowGroup",
  options = list(rowGroup = list(
    dataSrc = c(2),
    columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(2))),
    startRender = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "
      function (rows, group) {
      
            function addCell(tr, content, colSpan = 1) {
                let td = document.createElement('th');
             
                td.colSpan = colSpan;
                td.textContent = content;
             
                console.log(td);
      
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }

            let count = rows.count();
      
            let mean =
                rows
                  .data()
                  .pluck(1)
                  .reduce((a, b) => a + b) / rows.count();
      
            mean = DataTable.render
              .number(null, null, 0)
              .display(mean);
      
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            
            addCell(tr, group, 2);
            addCell(tr, 'n = ' + count + ', mean = ' + mean, 1);
            
            return tr;
        }
      ")
  ))
)


UPDATE As an JS beginner I guess that there are more elegant approaches. But here is one approach which instead of using the data on the displayed rows filters the table data for the group and computes the count and the mean for the whole dataset:
DT::datatable(chickwts,
  rownames = TRUE,
  extensions = "RowGroup",
  elementId = "example",
  options = list(rowGroup = list(
    dataSrc = c(2),
    columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(2))),
    startRender = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "
      function (rows, group) {

            function addCell(tr, content, colSpan = 1) {
                let td = document.createElement('th');

                td.colSpan = colSpan;
                td.textContent = content;

                console.log(td);

                tr.appendChild(td);
            }

            var table_data = $('#example table').DataTable().data();
      
            let vals = table_data.filter(k => k[2] === group).map(k => k[1]);
      
            let count = vals.count();

            let mean =
                vals
                  .reduce((a, b) => a + b) / vals.count();

            mean = DataTable.render
              .number(null, null, 0)
              .display(mean);

            let tr = document.createElement('tr');

            addCell(tr, group, 2);
            addCell(tr, 'n = ' + count + ', mean = ' + mean, 1);

            return tr;
        }
      "
    )
  ))
)



Thank you, this works. It gives me quite a bit to study and try to understand.

I'm noticing that aggregated values change depending on the number of rows of a group that are displayed. I am wondering if there is a way to get the actual aggregates rather than aggregates of currently displayed records.

See my update for an approach to get the count and mean for the whole dataset instead of just the displayed rows.

Very cool. It looks like the magic is in var table_data = $('#example table').DataTable().data(); and let vals = table_data.filter(k => k[2] === group).map(k => k[1]);. It seems like you call the whole table, filter to the groups, and get the aggregated values. This is really helpful.

An alternative would be to create a new column as string with the name of the grouped column pasted with the count and mean. You use this new column to group and then use columnDefs to hide it.
For example:
chickwts <- chickwts %>%
   dplyr::group_by(feed) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(feed_extended = paste0(feed, 
        " (n = ", 
        dplyr::n(),
        ", mean = ", 
        mean(weight), 
        ")"))

DT::datatable(
   chickwts,
   extensions = "RowGroup",
   options = list(
      rowGroup = list(
      dataSrc = c(3)
   ),
   columnDefs = list(
      list(
         visible = FALSE,
         targets = 3
      )
   )
))

I didn't try that code exactly, but I did with a similar scenario and it worked with my data.
